# Как отредактировать файл и вывести в браузер

Tags: php

Есть кешированные html страницы на хостинге. Необходимо их выводить в браузер пользователя, для чего используется такой код:

```
if($dh = @fopen(@$cachefile, "r"))
{
    fpassthru($dh);
    exit;
}
```

Но теперь появилась задача: в определённых случаях редактировать кешированный файл перед выводом в браузер пользователя. Т.е. нужно выполнить подобное:

```
if($dh = @fopen(@$cachefile, "r"))
{
    str_replace("%body%", "black", $dh); // Заменить часть контента
    fpassthru($dh);
    exit;
}
```

Как это лучше всего сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю использовать:

```php
<?php
$page = @file_get_contents($cachefile);
if ($page === false)
    exit("Ошибка: Не удалось прочитать файл!");
// Замена текста
$page = str_replace("%old_text%", "new text", $page);
// Лично я использую массив для замены множества значений
$arguments = [
    "%old_text_2%" => "new text 2"
];
foreach ($arguments as $key => $value)
    $page = str_replace($key, $value, $page);
echo $page;
```